# How to calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k^{\frac{1}{k}}}$?

Tags: limits

Well it seems impossible...

Does this limit even exist (in R)?

I calculated this limit with mathematica and I got $e^{2i\space0\space to\space \pi}$ but I don't know what that is...

How can I tell $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k^{\frac{1}{k}}}$ does not converge?

Thanks.

Comment: No idea why there would be a $(-1)^k$ term there.

Comment: Is this defined for $k\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: yes I believe it is

Comment: Well, as $k^{1/k}\to 1$, this sequence diverges

Comment: why the downvote? It is a good question, maybe it would be better on mathematica stackechange but i see no reason to downvote.

Comment: @homiee please say when you add another question to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `Mathematica` says here, that no limit exists. The output

```
Exp[2 I Intervall[{0,Pi}]]
```

Just say that all values that are taken for big enough $k$ are in the form
$$\exp(2i x)$$ 
with $x\in[0,\pi]$.  `Mathematica` thinks $k\in \mathbb{R}$, that is why it gives an Intervall, for $k\in \mathbb{N}$ the sequence has the two accumulation points $-1$ and $1$.

Because $k^\frac{1}{k}$ is converging to $1$, and always greater equal 1, it gives this result.

For the series use that it necessary that the sequence that is summated must be a to $0$ converging sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by "must be a to 0 converging sequence"? Does it mean that the sequence must converge to 0?

Comment: Lets say $s_n:= \sum_{k=0}^n$ converges to $L$.  Than obviously $s_{n-1}$ converges to $L$ too. Than $s_n -s_{n-1}$ converges to zero, and $s_n-s_{n-1}=a_{n}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint by $k^{1/k}=e^{\frac{1}{k}\log k}$ we find that $\lim_{k\to\infty}k^{1/k}=1$ and the sequence $((-1)^k)$ has not a limit, so what you can conclude?